# How to search for dash (-) in kibana?

Tags: kibana

I am using kibana 6.4 and trying to search for a dash, but it seems it does not work.

e.g I have a such field

```
field_1: -
```

and I need to find all the documents where the 'filed_1' is eq to dash(-).

I have tried some combinations

```
field_1: '-'
field_1: "-"
field_1: "\-"
field_1: -
...
```

no one works correctly.

All the results are empty but without any search, I can see that there are some fields with an expected result.